# Magento site invoking install script sometimes

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm facing a strange issue in Magento. Sometimes my site is working fine and sometimes it is asking for installation. What could be the reason for this kind of issue? Please help me out, guys. Thanks.

Comment: You need install all patches that were provided by magento.

Comment: @Davids Thanks for your reply.Let me try the same.

Comment: Without getting to admin panel is there a way to get the patches installed?